# IS There a proof that if 4 points on a parabola have x coordinates summing to 0 then there is a circle that contains them all?

Tags: proof-writing, circles, conic-sections

So I observed that it seems like if the x coordinates of 4 points on a parabola sum to 0 they all lie on a circle, is this true and is there any way to prove it? If so what is the proof?  Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided some more of your own thoughts - for instance, are you looking for a solution of a more geometric or algebraic nature? If it's algebraic, for instance, is the difficulty in phrasing the question via algebra, or is it in solving the resulting equations. (I also might note that, while I'm sure there are nice geometric solutions, it's not so clear from your question whether "I encoded it algebraically and solved the systems with a computer" is a helpful answer)

Comment: Doesn't look right to me. If you can find four points on a parabola that *don’t* lie on any circle, then by moving the parabola to the right or left a suitable amount, you should be able to get the sum of the $x$-coords of the moved points to be zero. (Were you, perchance, looking at $y=x^2$ and taking symmetric pairs of points ? )

Answer (score 1):

Consider the parabola $$y=x^2$$

Consider an arbitrary circle with midpoint $(a,b)$ and radius $r$. The corresponding equation is $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

The intersections $(x,y)$ of the circle with the parabola thus have $$r^2=(x-a)^2+(x^2-b)^2=x^4+(1-2b)x^2+(-2a)x+(a^2+b^2)\\x^4+(1-2b)x^2+(-2a)x+(a^2+b^2-r^2)=0$$

If the circle intersects at four points $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_4,y_4)$, this polynomial will have four roots $x_1,...,x_4$, so it equals $(x-x_1)...(x-x_4)$. The $x^3$-coefficient of this will be $-x_1-...-x_4$. So we find that the sum of the $x$-coordinates of the four intersections will have to be zero.

Note that the existence of three different real roots of the polynomial implies the existence of a fourth root, although you might find a root of higher order.

Now if you take any three points on the parabola, there is a unique circle through all three points. The corresponding parabola thus has three different real roots, and thus a fourth, and the sum of the four equals zero.

Thus, if you take four arbitrary points on the parabola with sum of $x$-coordinates zero, the first will lie on the unique circle through the other three, so they all lie on a circle.

Comment: It seems to me this proves the converse of the claim in the question.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, sorry. I posted an answer, but then found a mistake. So I had to rewrite some parts, and you were in the unfortunate situation of seeing an unfinished answer. It should be correct now. My idea was that the converse implies the claim in question, so that is why I first showed the converse.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the parabola $y=ax^2$. Then your statement is equivalent to the existence of a point $(x’,y’): (x_i-x’)^2+(y_i-y’)^2=c, \forall{}i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ where $c$ is fixed. This is equivalent to $x_i$ being the roots of some polynomial $ P(x)=a^2x^4+(1-2y’a)x^2-2x’x-c’$ for some $x’,y’,c’\in\mathbb{R}$ (here $c’={x’}^2+{y’}^2-c$). This is obviously possible since $1-2y’a,2x’,c’$ are independent values and the coefficient of $x^3$ is always $\sum{}x_i=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The result is true, at least for the parabola $4ay=x^2$. Here is a thoroughly unenlightening algebraic proof.

Let the parabola be parametrised by $x=2at$, $y=at^2$. Then if we consider the curve as lying in the complex plane, it takes the form $ z = x+iy = 2at + iat^2 $. We may then take the four points as $z_k = 2at_k + iat_k^2$ for $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, with .

Four points in the complex plane lie on a circle if and only if their cross-ratio is real, that is, if
$$ \Im \left( \frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)} \right) = 0 . $$
A tedious computation reveals that the left-hand side of this equation is
$$ \frac{2(t_1-t_2)(t_1-t_3)(t_2-t_4)(t_3-t_4)(t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4)}{(t_2-t_3)(t_1-t_4)(4+(x_2+x_3)^2)(4+(x_1+x_4)^2)} , $$
which is zero if $t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4=0$, as required.

---

More persuasively, perhaps, we want to find a circle through the four points $(2at_k,at_k^2)$. Such a circle has the form
$$ (x-A)^2 + (y-B)^2 = r^2 , \tag{1} $$
and we want expressions for $A,B,r$ so that $ (2at_k,at_k^2) $ satisfy this; i.e. they are the four roots of the equation
$$ (2at-A)^2 + (at^2-B)^2  - r^2 = 0 , $$
which we can multiply out to find
$$ t^4 + \left(4-2\frac{B}{a}\right)t^2 - 4\frac{A}{a} t + \frac{A^2+B^2-r^2}{a^2} = 0 . $$
Using Vieta's formulae, the roots of this equation satisfy
$$ t_1 + t_2 + t_3 + t_4 = 0 \\
\sum_{i<j} t_i t_j = 4-2\frac{B}{a} \\
\sum_{i<j<k} t_i t_j t_k = 4\frac{A}{a} \\
t_1 t_2 t_3 t_4 = \frac{A^2+B^2-r^2}{a^2} , $$
which gives expressions for $A,B,r$ in terms of the $t_k$. It's not obvious that $r^2>0$ with this approach, but it turns out that if the condition on the $t_k$ is satisfied, it is a product of positive terms. Hence we find real $A,B,r$ so that the four points lie on the circle $(1)$.